# Understanding .NET memory mangement and profiling

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, profiling

I have a C# application which consumes absolutely inadequate amounts of memory which is steadily increasing. I tried to use Visual Studio 2019 memory profiler to find the problem. I was expecting to see gigabytes of objects of some specific type and find the leakage, but instead I found a totally normal objects set with no more then 800 KB per type.

[image: Heap snapshot]

Snapshot size also indicates normal heap size of 8MB while process memory approaches 5GB!

[image: Profile screenshot]

My idea is that GC for some reason refuses to collect unreferenced objects, but GC marks do regularilly appear on the memory chart. I also tried cleaning gen 2 objects by calling GC.Collect() explicitly.

Looks like I don't understand some basic concept of memory handling. 
What have I missed? What can I do to find the problem?

UPD: I've also found a strange issue. I'm using a FluentFtp client in my software, and when i've found these entries in the heap (i don't use any other network functionality)

[image: FluentFtp]

I thought I've found the leak. These numbers don't decrease ever, even disposing a thread doesn't help!
But when I extracted the ftp code to the separate application, and the problem disappeared.

```
FtpClient client = new FtpClient(<ip>);
client.Credentials = ...
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   client.Connect();
   client.Disconnect();
}
```

In the end I had only 63 of these objects! And note that private memory is just 86 times bigger than the heap, instead of 625 in case of my application.
How is it possible that EXACTLY same code produces different results in my application?

[image: FluentFtpProfiling]

[image: FluentFtp heap]

Comment: It seems to me like you're leaking memory because that class isn't cleaning itself up properly. Have you tried running a new instance per connection instead of reusing the same one? As for the GC, I've read that a good way to ensure that the GC does its thing is call Dispose() and then setting the object to null when you're done with it.

Comment: Yes, my first idea was that it's a bug in FluentFtp, but it can't be reproduced outside of my software. Yes, I've tried running a new instance per connection, with `using` statement, so i'm sure it's disposed properly. I even tried disposing the whole thread.

Comment: Try to put your ftp client into `using` statement to properly manage it's disposal

Comment: I don't need to dispose it, but, as I mentioned, I've tried it.

Comment: Taking a look at the objects and handles in your memory screenshot, there is definately something that is being created and not disposed properly. I believe the reason is that there seems to be some awaits or threads that are launched and never finish. Look at the sheer quantity of  Wait handles and callbacks. Its almost as if you're spinning up instances of something on a new thread each time, then calling an async function in the thread, then waiting for that async to finish, which it never does, so the thread never dies. Have you looked at the number of threads for your process in taskmgr?

Comment: Also, look at how the object count for other objects is always an increment larger than that of the threadpool wait handle count. So yeah, you're definately spinning up threads that aren't finishing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was indeed a FluentFtp problem. I changed it to another library and everything's returned to normal. 
But i'm still usure why I couldn't reproduce this issue in separate application.